# unable to find a device matching 0451:f432

Tags: debugging, msp430, texas-instruments

recently I bought a msp430g2553 launchpad, I use ubuntu20 as my OS and Iinstalled gcc-msp, so far ok.. but when I try to debug like this "mspdebug rf2500" but i received this error:

usbutil: unable to find a device matching 0451:f432

I am a noob so I do not how to solve.. Any idea?

Comment: not a programming question.

Comment: Does it show up in the output of lsusb?

Comment: lsusb show me Bus 001 Device 048: ID 2047:0013 Texas Instruments MSP Tools Driver.. I do not know how to match both rf2500 and msp430 address